# Windows Server Backup, drive is doing full backup instead of incremental

Tags: windows-sbs-2008, windows-server-backup, vss

We currently have a windows small business server 2008, that is being backed up using the default SBS tools (windows server backup). Things seem to work properly, but the backups are taking a very long time (up to 12 hours). Everything is configured to use incremental backups, but when I look through the logs I notice our C: drive is actually doing a full 65GB backup every run, not an incremental one. Does anyone know why this is happening and what we can do to fix it?

I'm not sure if it is the default, but I noticed that shadow copies are disabled for the C: drive, could this be preventing incremental backups from being performed?

Answer (score 2):

What are you backing up to? If you're backing up to a shared network folder, WSB will only store one full backup per server, each new backup wiping out the last.

Also yes you need VSS.

And it could also happen if more than 50% of the source files have changed since the last backup.

Comment: We are backing up to an iSCSI target. Do I need to enable VSS in the volume properties on the C: drive?

Comment: Oh, also, are you choosing the "Faster backup performance" option in WSB?

Answer (score -1):

If your drives are set to ReFS format instead of NTFS format Windows Server will ignore the incremental setting and perform a full backup on the ReFS format drives instead.

Comment: Please when answering old questions, make sure that your answer is actually relevant. This is really not a useful contribution with ReFS only being supported for Windows Server 2012 and later  and the OP running Windows SBS 2008 (although, in 2024 probably not even running that system at all anymore)