# Windows Server Backup creating absolute backups instead of incremental to network share

Tags: windows-server-2016, windows-server-backup

I created a daily backup to a network share and as the backup setup specifies, it should be incremental, but it has been transfering the whole disk to the share instead of actually creating incremental backups. This may be a possible duplicate of [Windows Server Backup, drive is doing full backup instead of incremental](https://serverfault.com/questions/482798/windows-server-backup-drive-is-doing-full-backup-instead-of-incremental;) no response was given to this problem in that thread.

I can only imagine I need to enable VSS but I'd like to avoid that if possible. In case I do need to enable VSS; how much disk space does it use in relation to the original data? If shadow copies are to heavy there is no way I can enable that because I don't have much disk space left.

Comment: I'll try enabling VSS. It seems like you can get an estimate shadow copy size by running "vssadmin list shadowstorage" on the cmd. In my case it looks like it is a 4.6:1 ratio (original:vss)

Comment: The answer to the question you referenced is correct. That is the expected behavior when using network share as the backup target.