# Windows Server 2022 does not perform incremental backup for source data volume

Tags: windows, backup, windows-server-2022, wbadmin

Windows Server 2022 is always doing full backup and not incremental backup.

I've checked this 10 year old question [Windows Server Backup, drive is doing full backup instead of incremental](https://serverfault.com/questions/482798/windows-server-backup-drive-is-doing-full-backup-instead-of-incremental) but there was nothing that can help me.

Additional Info:

1. Software: Windows Server Backup on Windows Server 2022 version 21h1.
2. Backup is done to a local external 4TB hard disk drive. (No network)
3. Performance option is set to do faster backups.
4. I tried setting performance options to custom and then explicitly
   selecting the drive that has the data to do a faster backup which I
   assume is incremental. But it keeps on doing a full backup.
5. I tried both VSS copy and backup options, still doing full backup.
6. I recreated the schedule, still doing a full backup.
7. The same configuration backs up the C drive as incremental, but data volume still doing a full backup.
8. I did manual backup; it keeps on doing a full backup.
9. The backup external disk drive was configured to be dedicated for backups, it was doing full backup; when I change it back so that backup is configured to backup on a volume, it did a full backup as well.
10. Data size is ~950GB
11. I've done this before but on Windows Server 2012 and it did a full backup the first time, and then subsequent backup operations were incremental which is the expected behavior.

Comment: Currently experiencing the same problem with Windows Server 2022 backup. Have you managed to find a solution? After the backup, it seems that the bit archive file is not being properly cleared!

Comment: Unfortunately, no solution yet!

Answer (score 0):

Check the Volume Shadow Copy service, it should be enabled.

Comment: It is enabled and set to "Manual Start". I did start it manually and started a backup afterwards, the same happens, always a full backup for my data volume